# Unpack tuple to 'format()' string

Tags: python, string, tuples

I have tuple with 6 int values, and want to print them with specified separators...

```
tuple_code = (10, 20, 30, 40, 11, 117)
```

..and want to print them with diffrent separators to string:

```
10-20:30.40.11*117
```

How to unpack tuple properly in this case? What I did so far and looks a bit messy for me.

```
def to_readable_format(self):
    i_code = iter(self.code)
    code = "{}-{}:{}.{}.{}*{}".format(str(next(i_code)), str(next(i_code)), 
                                      str(next(i_code)), str(next(i_code)),
                                      str(next(i_code)), str(next(i_code)), )
    return code
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [argument unpacking syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) like `code = "{}-{}:{}.{}.{}*{}".format(*self.code)`. No need to explicitly cast to `str` if all your tuple entries are integers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the unpacking operator `*` directly:

```
def to_readable_format(tpl):
#        i_code = iter(self.code)
        code = "{}-{}:{}.{}.{}*{}".format(*tpl)
        return code
    
to_readable_format(tuple_code)
```

Output:

```
'10-20:30.40.11*117'
```

Comment: thanks, I've changed to: ```return "{}-{}:{}.{}.{}*{}".format(*tpl)```